# Uncaught ReferenceError: showTreeDropdownContent is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

I make an ajax request and put the response in the container with id 'treeContainer'. When I click button with class 'btntreedropdown' I get Uncaught ReferenceError in the browser console.

I have seen other similar questions, but none of them seemed to be similar of this. What can be problem?

I intentionally attach image to this question, because I think it is more readable.

[image]

This is the method I use to get data:

```
function getTopicTree(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = event.srcElement.innerHTML.toString();

    $.get('/Teacher/HistoryTopic/Load', { root: value })
        .done(function (result) {
            document.getElementById('treeContainer').innerHTML = result;
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code on how you put the AJAX response into the div? You might be corrupting the button during that step.

Comment: Try to put your `<script></script>` tag after the </body> tag. And try again.

Comment: I will update my question. I Can't put <script></script> tags after </body> because it is part of response.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If the `<script>` tag is inside the `<div id="treeContainer">`, won't it get overwritten?

Comment: Everything in treeContainer is the response of ajax request.